# How to map [Color] to [String:Color] using ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I'm trying to map JSON of an Array type to a Dictionary and i'm not quite sure how to do it using ObjectMapper.

Example JSON:

```
{ 
  "colors": [
   { 
    "id": "red",
    "r": "255",
    "g": "255",
    "b": "255"
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following. Map it to an `array` first then using the `didSet` map it to the dictionary.

```
class MyClass: Mappable {
    private var arrayColors = [MyClass2] {
    didSet {
            var mapTypes = [String:MyClass2]?
            for obj in arrayColors {
                mapTypes[obj.id] = obj
            }

            types = mapTypes
        }
    }

    var colors:[String:MyClass2] = [String:MyClass2]()

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        arrayColors <- map["colors"]
    }
}
```